# How to make the name of a type predicate available for a template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, predicate, c++-concepts

I have just started to learn C++'s templates using Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++" (second edition). In chapter 19.3.3, during the process of implementing a `vector`, the writers introduce the concept of *concept* as follows:

> ... We call a set of requirements on a template argument a *concept* ... In C++14, we can make that explicit:

```cpp
template<typename T>        // for all types T
    requires Element<T>()   // such that T is an Element
class vector {
        //...
};
```

> This shows that a concept is really a type predicate, that is, a compile-time-evaluated (`constexpr`) function that returns `true` if the type argument (here, `T`) has the properties required by the concept (here, `Element`) and `false` if it does not.

In another book written by Bjarne Stroustrup ("A Tour of C++", second edition, chapter 6.2.1), the writer gives a similar example:

```cpp
template<Element T>
class Vector {
private:
    T* elem;    // elem points to an array of sz elements of type T
    int sz;
    //...
};
```

However, this time the writer states:

> ... C++ does not officially support concepts before C++20 ...

I tried to run above code (in Visual Studio 2022 using C++20) but it seems that the identifier `Element` is undefined ([C2061](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2061?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2061)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170)). I wonder if `Element` (and many other *concepts* stated by Stroustrup in the books) is defined in the standard library? How could we make the name available to use?

Comment: `Element` is not in the standard library. You can define `Element` yourself, but it's obnoxiously complicated to do so given the requirements of `std::vector`. Worse still, many of the requirements on `std::vector` is not on the entire class template, but separate for each member function.

Answer (score -6):

> I tried to run above code (in Visual Studio 2022 using C++20) but it seems that the identifier Element is undefined

I think you misunderstood what was being said. In particular, the author was trying to explain the concept of "concepts"(by giving an example) that uses some predefined `Element`.

You're getting the error because your program does not have any such construct called `Element`. That is, to use `Element<T>()` you must first declare that there is one such thing called `Element`.

Comment: So, those concepts like `Element` are not defined in the standard library? The writer lists and uses many such concepts without defining them in the book...

Comment: This is plain wrong, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: @CPPL No `Element`(afaik) is not in the standard library. As i said, the author is trying to explain the topic of concepts using some arbitrary construct named `Element`. Also note that non type template parameter of class type are allowed from C++20(and onwards) only.

Comment: @PasserBy Which part is plain wrong? Are you referring to the last [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/xT8cTKWWr) or something else?

Comment: `Element` is supposed to be a concept.

Comment: @PasserBy Yes, my point is that in any case `Element` must be there so that we can use it. Without having anything called `Element` we cannot use it.

Comment: `T` is not a non-type template parameter because `Element` is supposed to be a concept, and the snippets you show is not what the question is asking about.

Comment: @PasserBy I have removed the first part of my answer and also the snippets. Now just the explanation is there.